# This cat can see you

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

Since rebus puzzles are starting to pick up again and I *love* them, here's one!
Added a few more images to make more sense :)

[image: bored man] [image: 4] [image: it's a cat I swear]

Comment: Is that the full image? Looks a bit cropped.

Comment: Yep, that's it. just a cat on a shelf. The garbage on the shelf ain't important :^)

Comment: Does the "a" in the cat's mouth have something to with it? Is 'accept' even close for the first picture?

Comment: boring for boring?

Comment: @Alto The A does have something to do with it, yes. Gary's choice of words is important :)

Comment: @Duck not quite :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this be-

> Sure, for a price.

Reason-

> the word gary uses is -sure, 4 can be for,letter on cat's mouth A, Cat On Shelf gives COS, there is also a letter T seen on the picture which makes it- COST, i.e. price

---

New Guess:

> Surgery for a cataract. (Sure+Gary) + 4 +a + (cat+rack+t)

Comment: oooh, I like this. Alas, any words in the rebus are indeed important, making Gary's name important too ;) While my comment above addressed the object as a "shelf" in order to not give anything away too son, I should perhaps say it is a synonym to "shelf". You're correct in using the T at the very end!

Comment: Oh and the title can have something to do with it too :)

Comment: Aha! There it is- your new guess is indeed correct :) Wonderful job!